How to setup Ebay SetNotificationPreferences Flask Python
Im struggling to receive SOAP notifications sent from Ebay. I run this function after I obtain the user's access/auth token when connecting to my application.
Here is the function:
def setup_notifications(user):
        try:
            # if EbayAuth.is_token_expired(user):
            #     EbayAuth.refresh_token(user)

            api = EbayAPI.get_api_connection(user)
            # print(user["ebay_access_token"])
            preferences = {
                "RequesterCredentials": {"eBayAuthToken": user["ebay_access_token"]},
                "ApplicationDeliveryPreferences": {
                    "AlertEmail": "mailto:example@email.com",
                    "AlertEnable": "Enable",
                    "ApplicationEnable": "Enable",
                    "ApplicationURL": "https://mywebsite.com/ebay/webhook",
                    "DeviceType": "Platform",
                    "DeliveryURLDetails": {
                        "DeliveryURL": "https://mywebsite.com/ebay/webhook",
                        "DeliveryURLName": "Default",
                        "Status": "Enable",
                    },
                },
                "UserDeliveryPreferenceArray": {
                    "NotificationEnable": [
                        {"EventType": "ItemListed", "EventEnable": "Enable"},
                        {"EventType": "ItemSold", "EventEnable": "Enable"},
                        {"EventType": "ItemRevised", "EventEnable": "Enable"},
                        {"EventType": "ItemClosed", "EventEnable": "Enable"},
                    ]
                },
            }

            response = api.execute("SetNotificationPreferences", preferences)
            return response.dict().get("Ack") == "Success"

        except Exception as e:
            print(f"Error setting up notifications: {str(e)}")
            return False

The error I am getting when I trigger an event is:
    {
      "DeliveryStatus": "Rejected",
      "DeliveryURL": "https://mywebsite.com/ebay/webhook",
      "DeliveryURLName": "Default",
      "ErrorMessage": "INVALID_AUTH_TOKEN_STATUS:Invalidated token: Token does not exist",
      "ExpirationTime": "2024-11-05T09:37:32.000Z",
      "ReferenceID": "ITEMID",
      "Type": "ItemRevised"
    }] 

As you can see it says token does not exist but I can confirm that the user token does exist and is retrievable when print(user["ebay_access_token"]) right before the parameters are set.
In my eBay Developer Portal, I have the webhook URL set in the notifications tab.
Im not sure what I am missing. am I supposed to use my auth token? or the users? or a random one? also if I have to use a auth token that expires how do I keep this up to date? do I need to monitor my user's tokens and update the notification preferences every time?
Here is my webhook.
@ebay_bp.route("/ebay/webhook", methods=["POST", "HEAD"])
def ebay_webhook():
    if request.method == "HEAD":
        return Response(status=200)

    try:
        content_type = request.headers.get("Content-Type", "")
        if not content_type.startswith("text/xml"):
            print(f"Unexpected content type: {content_type}")
            return Response(status=200)

        soap_message = request.get_data(as_text=True)
        if not soap_message:
            return Response(status=200)

        root = ET.fromstring(soap_message)
        namespaces = {
            "soapenv": "http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/",
            "xsd": "http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema",
            "xsi": "http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance",
        }

        header = root.find(".//soapenv:Header", namespaces)
        if header is not None:
            timestamp = header.find(".//Timestamp")
            signature = header.find(".//NotificationSignature")

            if timestamp is not None and signature is not None:
                msg = f"{timestamp.text}{CLIENT_DEV_ID}{CLIENT_ID}{CLIENT_SECRET}"
                computed_sig = base64.b64encode(
                    hashlib.md5(msg.encode("ascii")).digest()
                ).decode()

                if computed_sig != signature.text:
                    print("Invalid notification signature")
                    return Response(status=200)

        body = root.find(".//soapenv:Body", namespaces)
        if body is not None:
            notification_data = {}
            for elem in body.iter():
                tag = elem.tag.split("}")[-1]
                if elem.text and elem.text.strip():
                    notification_data[tag] = elem.text.strip()
            event_type = notification_data.get("NotificationEventName")
            if event_type:
                print(f"Received {event_type} notification")
                print(f"Notification data: {notification_data}")

    except ET.ParseError as e:
        print(f"XML parsing error: {str(e)}")
    except Exception as e:
        print(f"Error processing notification: {str(e)}")

    # Always return 200 OK as required by eBay
    return Response(status=200)

I understand I could be missing a few things when handling the SOAP. The documentation on the platform notifications is minimal with samples and examples.
Any help would be great thank you.
